# Not reload recyclerview after screen rotation

Tags: android

I would like to not reload the `RecyclerView` after screen rotation from portrait to landscape.

I'm using `onSaveInstanceState` to save list from adapter, and restore it inside `onActivityCreated`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(mAdapter != null) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", mAdapter.getOriginalList());
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

But there is problem, the `RecyclerView` is reconstructed after each screen rotation. What is wrong ?

Comment: Did you have add below line to your activity in manifest.xml file ?



android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Comment: @Vickyexpert I did it, but there is other problem: I have 2 different layout's for landscape and portrait, and this line is disabled the landscape layout.

Comment: @VLenovos, OK then you need to set adapter on configuration changed programetically then only it can be possible to set data without reloading

Comment: *I would like to not reload the RecyclerView...* Then do not call reload code(which obviously is not in the question) `if(savedInstanceState != null) { /*use savedInstanceState to get data*/ } else { /*load the data from whatever you loading from*/ }` ... [you can also use non UI retainable fragment for that](http://selvin.pl/MainActivity.java.txt)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set adapter on configuration changed programetically then only it can be possible to set data without reloading.

Something like below,

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if(mAdapter != null)
              your_recycle_view.setAdapter(mAdapter);

     }
```